# ActiveMQTextMessages are kept in memory after they are consumed from topic

Tags: memory, activemq-classic, message

So i have a problem. I am running an embedded apache.activemq.broker in my application which has a topic. i have one producer which sends small messages to the topic and consumer consumes them.
The problem is the applications memory footprint just keeps growing and growing to the point when it takes up several gigabytes of memory after some days. I did a memory profiling with JProfiler and noticed that alot of instances of type ActiveMQTextMessage are kept in the memory. 
This is how i set up my broker

```
        BrokerService brokerService = new BrokerService();
        brokerService.setUseJmx(false);
        brokerService.setUseLocalHostBrokerName(false);
        brokerService.addConnector(tenantConfiguration.getConnectionString());
        brokerService.setBrokerName(tenantConfiguration.getBrokerComponentIdentifier());
        brokerService.setPersistenceAdapter(persistenceAdapterFromConnectionString);

        SystemUsage systemUsage = new SystemUsage();
        brokerService.setSystemUsage(systemUsage);
        brokerService.setDestinationPolicy(createDestinationPolicyForBrokerService());
```

And here is how i set up destination policy

```
private PolicyMap createDestinationPolicyForBrokerService() {
    PolicyMap policyMap = new PolicyMap();

    List<PolicyEntry> policyEntries = new ArrayList<>();

    ConstantPendingMessageLimitStrategy constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy = new ConstantPendingMessageLimitStrategy();
    constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy.setLimit(10);

    PolicyEntry queuePolicyEntry = new PolicyEntry();
    queuePolicyEntry.setPrioritizedMessages(true);
    queuePolicyEntry.setGcInactiveDestinations(true);
    queuePolicyEntry.setInactiveTimoutBeforeGC(86400);
    queuePolicyEntry.setQueue(">");
    queuePolicyEntry.setPendingMessageLimitStrategy(constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy);

    PolicyEntry topicPolicyEntry = new PolicyEntry();
    topicPolicyEntry.setTopic(">");
    topicPolicyEntry.setGcInactiveDestinations(true);
    topicPolicyEntry.setInactiveTimoutBeforeGC(5000);
    topicPolicyEntry.setPendingMessageLimitStrategy(constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy);
    topicPolicyEntry.setUseCache(false);

    policyEntries.add(queuePolicyEntry);
    policyEntries.add(topicPolicyEntry);

    policyMap.setPolicyEntries(policyEntries);
    return policyMap;
}
```

Here is screenshot of one of messages outgoing references
[Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuEKh.png)

And here is an image when i click on "Show paths to GC root"
[Gc root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYv86.png)

EDIT:
Here is how i setup the DurableConsumer

```
private NMSConnectionFactory _connnectionFactory;
private IConnection _connection;
private ISession _session;

 public void Start()
        {
            _connection = _connnectionFactory.CreateConnection(queueUser, queuePwd);
            _connection.Start();
            _session = _connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TopicName))
            {
                   _topicConsumer = _session.CreateDurableConsumer(SessionUtil.GetTopic(_session, TopicName), ConsumerName, null, false);
                _topicConsumer.Listener += TopicConsumerOnListener;
            }
        }
```

And this is how we i publish messages to topic

```
 public void PublishMessage(string message)
    {
        using (var connection = _connnectionFactory.CreateConnection(user, pwd))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Start();
                ActiveMQTopic topic = new ActiveMQTopic(TopicName);
                using (var session = connection.CreateSession())
                using (var producer = session.CreateProducer(topic))
                {
                    var textMessage = producer.CreateTextMessage(message);
                    producer.Send(textMessage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why the messages are not being removed after they are consumed?

Thanks

Comment: No code to help see what you are doing so hard to say, the GC root appears to be linked to a durable subscription so it would appear it is holding them for some durable subscriber.  Add more info to help us out.

Comment: I have added more code to the first post

Comment: After some more analysis i found out that this is due to ACTIVEMQ_ACKS table that camel is controlling. This is a table where broker is storing consumers of topics. I noticed that when i restart both broker application and consumer application the broker adds a new consumer in that table with its unique id but the old consumer is not removed so the messages are kept in memory forever because the previous consumer is not alive anymore since we restarted everything. Is there a way to tell broker to remove old consumers from the table?

Comment: solved the problem by adding my own clientId in connection to topic

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding my own clientId to connection of topic

```
_connection = _connnectionFactory.CreateConnection(queueUser, queuePwd);
_connection.ClientId = "MY CLIENT ID";
_connection.Start();
```

That way no new consumer rows are created on restart.